# Is there a way to execute a multiple test methods in order on parameterized data

Tags: bdd, junit5

I am using JUnit5 and and wanted to construct my test class with ordered methods over a set of data.
So far I've looked into nested tests but I cannot seem to get the desired output

Is there anyway to do this? Can someone maybe just point me in the right direction because I've been tackling this for hours.

```
@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("getTestData")
@Order(1)
void shouldGetTestCaseNumber(Map<Object, Object> excelData) {
    System.out.println(excelData.get("Test Case "));

}

@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("getTestData")
@Order(2)
void shouldGetEntitlement(Map<Object, Object> excelData) {
    System.out.println(excelData.get("Entitlement"));
}


Collection<Arguments> getTestData() throws IOException {
    TestDataService testDataService = new TestDataService();
    List<Arguments> data = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Object[] d: testDataService.getData()){
        data.add(Arguments.of(d));
    }
    return data;
}
```

Right now the output would have all test cases for shouldGetTestCaseNumber() followed by shouldGetEntitlement() but I would like a single test case as

Test Case 1

- shouldGetTestCaseNumber()
- shouldGetEntitlement()

Test Case 2

- shouldGetTestCaseNumber()
- shouldGetEntitlement()

Like I said, I would just life if someone could point me in the right direction and I could go from there

Comment: A complete individual test case should run [ shouldGetTestCaseNumber() shouldGetEntitlement()] in that order

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible with the current feature set.

There's an open issue for this at https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/871 ... and lot of related ones.

You may resort to dynamic tests and roll your own lightweight tests structure. But you'll loose all features that parameterized tests provide.

https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-dynamic-tests